# TYPO3 Search Indexed Engine Depth

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use TYPO3 7.6.10, crawler 5.0.6

I have the search page with the results.
I have all the pages indexed but the pages of 4 level are not found. How can I show on result page the 4 level pages?

Comment: Are those pages indexed? You can check that by using the backend module. Everything must be indexed to be found

Comment: yes those pages are indexed

Comment: i solved. the problem is a template defined inside the tree as root. sorry